# Location of password functionalitly in DDD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design, poco

I'm buidling an application using MVC 2, with EF 4, using the repository pattern and poco. I want to build a login page for Customers. Where should the functionality live that does things like checks password policy, validity and all other things login related. Would this live inside the POCO generated Customer Entity, should I create a seperate login class, or something else?

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under DDD, that functionality could be implemented as a Service, as it is not the responibility of the Customer to authenticate itself.

You can read a definition of Service [here](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/125).

Comment: So rather than place this functionality in the domain layer, you're saying it would be better placed in a seperate service layer?

Comment: No, not a service layer, a Domain Service (in the context of DDD). It is a  way to represent a way of dealing with operations between entities, which are not exclusive responsibilities of any of these entities.
More on this [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/17/ddd-services.aspx).

Comment: +1 - i agree. This is authentication related - which is not part of the domain, it's part of the presentation of the domain as a web application. Should be domain service.

Comment: @ CGK - Followup question, if the authentication is to implemented as a domain service then does that mean that the service needs access to a repository in order to get access to the data or is it ok to have a domain service access infrastructure such as a database without the need to go through a repository?

Comment: If you're applying DDD stricly, I think you should use the repository to access the data. In that way, you avoid having inconsistencies down the road.

Answer (score 1):

[Check](http://weblogs.asp.net/pgielens/archive/2006/05/31/Applying-the-Application-Layer-in-Domain-Driven-Design.aspx) this link, there are few points which might help you.

```
  "Where should the functionality live that does things like checks password policy,
 validity and all other things login related. Would this live inside the POCO generated 
 Customer Entity, should I create a seperate login class, or something else?"
```

Create separate model for Password and User, Pass them to domain service and let Customer repository handle the other task.

In addition have you [referred](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/) Sharp Architecture. this is builds upon MVC+DDD+NH+POCO. This will give you brief about what you looking for.

Comment: Strewth, that all looks fairly overwhelming. With your knowledge of Sharp Architecture is there anything in particular I should look at in relation to my login question?